# Limit data that users / roles are able to access

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I am trying to create a database for students in classes. As I will have multiple classes all with different users, how can I make sure that users are able to only see other users in their own class (or just information on themselves would be even more preferable), while only using 2 collections. One collection holding the class information and one collection holding all the user information. This is to ensure that there are no privacy breaches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#-redact--aggregation-).

Comment: @Joe If I am correct $redact is a client side function in the driver. This would still allow students to access the unique id's of other users and add data using their unique id. Is there any way to limit the find functionality to specific documents based on user is maybe more appropriate to ask for.